# Connect to Azure Data Lake gen2 using AdlsToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, azure-data-lake, google-cloud-composer

I am using Cloud Composer, which runs Apache Airflow, to copy data from Azure Data Lake Gen2 to Cloud Storage. I did some research and found this operator [AdlsToGoogleCloudStorageOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/adls_to_gcs/index.html). What I do not know yet is how to connect to the ADLS using the wasb and a storage account Key or SAS Token. I've not found any example showing this part of the process(getting connected to azure data lake).

do you suggest any piece of example code I might follow?.

Answer (score 1):

As per [1] (lines 33-34), “airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.adls_to_gcs.AdlsToGoogleCloudStorageOperator” is deprecated, use instead “airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.adls_to_gcs.ADLSToGCSOperator”.

You have several options in [2] to manage connections (from Airflow UI, CLI, etc.).

As you seem more inclined to use the python API, you can try setting a “Connection” object as in [3], then you can use the “conn_id” of this “Connection” object to set the “azure_data_lake_conn_id” parameter in the “ADLSToGCSOperator” operator.

[1] https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/adls_to_gcs.py

[2] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html

[3] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#generating-a-connection-uri